# Unable to exclude .cache from duplicity backup

Tags: command-line, duplicity

I wish to backup with `duplicity` (I use it often, usually without issues) `/etc` and `/root`. I wish to exclude `.cache` from the `/root` directory. I try:

```
duplicity incremental --full-if-older-than 30W --include /etc \
  --include /root --exclude '/root/.cache' --exclude / \
  --verbosity info / scp://TARGET
```

This generally works, but `/root/.cache` is included within backup. Instead of the `'/root/.cache'` I tried different expression patterns: `/root/.cache`, `"/root/.cache"`, `"**.cache"`, `'**.cache'`, `''**.cache''` and several others, with same result.

According to [duplicity manual](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) (I have 0.7.12 on openSUSE), expression `"**.cache"` should work well. Do I misread the manual or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilia,

order matters when excluding in duplicity. the parameters are used in the order given. in your example '/root/.cache' is compared to

```
--include /etc
--include /root <-- and matches here
--exclude '/root/.cache'
--exclude /
```

try to move the specific exclusion in front of the more general include eg.

```
--include /etc
--exclude /root/.cache
--include /root
--exclude /**
```

that should work. moving the cache out the root's home folder would work as well of course.

btw. file selection has it's own section in the duplicity man page
 http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect9

wrt. to `**.cache`, yes. it will work, but will exclude any path named '.cache' in the end. if you want the exact name you should use `**/.cache`.

finally, there is the `--exclude-if-present` parameter, which can be quite handy if there are just some folders to be excluded.

> --exclude-if-present filename
>   Exclude directories if filename is present. Allows the user to specify folders that they do not wish to backup by adding a specified file (e.g. ".nobackup") instead of maintaining a comprehensive exclude/include list. This option needs to come before any other include or exclude options.

..ede/duply.net